# React JS validate form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

Hello friends I'm pretty new to React JS so I want to ask you this:

I have a Parent and Child component. In Child component I have inputs (name,email etc) and in Parent component I have Button to save the input data in database.

My question is: How to validate inputs(i want them to be required) so the button can NOT call saveData function(to save in database) if the inputs are empty.

Here is Parent Component:

```
class Parent extends Component{
    saveData = (e) => {
      //some code
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child/>
                <Button color="primary" onClick={this.saveData}>Submit</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And here is Child Component:

```
class Child extends React.Component {

     onInputChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.onInputChange(e.target.name, e.target.value);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <FormGroup>
                <Input name="email" onChange={this.onInputChange}/>
            </FormGroup>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like there's a lot missing here. (1) you're reference a prop `onInputChange` that isn't being set in the parent component for the child (2) there's no state in the parent or child to track the input values (3) no implementation of any function to represent your `onInputChange` prop function

Comment: yes I just posted that part of the code that I think is important to show you what I want to do, I didn't want to bother you with a lot of code(of course there is a lot of missing things here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant see the implementation of your **`onInputChange`** function but looks like its coming from parent component.

So, if you have `onInputChange` in your parent component then, you can have a `disable` state that is passed to your `Button` component and you need to set that `disable` state when `onInputChange` is called i.e

```
onInputChange = (name, value) => {
    if(value === ''){
      this.setState({disable: true});
    }
    else{
      this.setState({
        name: value;
        disable:false
      })
    }
  }
```

And pass it to your button i.e.

```
 <Child />
 <Button color="primary" disabled={disable} onClick={this.saveData}>
```